# How to retrieve hierarchical data in inorder traversal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, tree, entity-framework-core

I have an element that represents a node in a tree structure.

```
public class Element
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Element Left { get; set; }
    public Element Right { get; set; }
}
```

I am maintaining a table with all those elements by foreign keys to the child elements.
If I try to get this tree back by using eager loading, I get the tree in postorder traversal:

```
public string GetExpression(int rootId)
{
    var root = _context.Set<Element>()
        .Include(r => r.Left)
        .Include(r => r.Right)
        .ToList();
}
```

Is there a way using queries to get the elements in inorder traversal? Or do I have to do this by myself recursively?

Answer (score 0):

The order that records are returned in a query is not defined unless you have an ORDERBY clause. So it is just luck that the example you gave returns them in a post-order.

I would suggest that you simply define in-order and post-order traversal methods and invoke them after you have loaded the entire set. You can omit the two .Include statements since EF will patch up the navigation relations during the load.